# iOS 11 Safari tries to download .dll file instead of showing HTTP response

Tags: ios, url, dll, download, safari

I've got a server setup with a URL structure like so:

```
mything.com/services/super.dll?why=doesnt&this=work
```

This URL returns some plaintext content with `Content-Type: text/plain`.

On iOS <= 10 and all Android browsers, it works as expected, and I see the plain text response.

On iOS 11, Safari tries to download super.dll. It gives me a screen telling me that super.dll is a Microsoft Windows application with a size of 1KB. I have the option to "Open in 'Files'" and "More...".

I have no idea what's going on under the hood that might cause this. Has anyone else seen this behavior?

Comment: I have seen it too. Curious to find out how to prevent it!